# Plotting points using AusMap plugin QGIS v3?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, australia, gda2020

I am trying to plot infrastructure points from the AusMap plugin but it does not align with my current CRS. The points are in GDA2020 - when I change my basemap to this it still does not align. I am struggling understanding CRS's in Australia!

Comment: When you say you change your basemap to GDA2020, are you changing the layer CRS in the layer properties (don't do that), or are you changing the project CRS in the project properties (this is the correct way)?

Comment: Did you get your basemap through the AusMap plugin, through the QuickMapServices plugin, or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin seems a bit buggy, or perhaps the map servers it links to are not very good. If the map is zoomed out to a whole world extent, the AusMaplayers won't load properly. It seems like the larger your map canvas extent is, the more difficult it is for the layer to load. After trying to load the layer for a while, I suspect that the plugin hits a time limit and gives up. Try removing all the layers from the AusMap plugin from your map. Next:

- Zoom in to only Australia, and add the layers *one at a time*. After adding each layer, don't interact with your computer at all until the layer loads (this may take up to a minute).
- If the layers won't load for the entire extent of Australia, zoom in to the extent of a town or city. Try to load one layer at a time, the same as above.

Once a layer loads successfully and displays correct information on your map, it should continue to work. But, if you zoom out (say to try to pan to a different area) the layers from this plugin will take a long time to load additional features for the larger area, and they may time out and give you an error message. Try turning off the layers from this plugin when you zoom and pan the map, and only turn them back on when you have the map in the area you want to focus on. It may help to put all the layers from the AusMap plugin in a group, so you can turn them off and back on all at once.

The fundamental issue is that the layers are remotely located and connecting to them is slow. Even with all the workarounds and coddling this plugin, some of the layers still don't work. If you need the layers from this plugin, it would behoove you to find sources where you can download the entire layer and work with it locally. Most of the web services the AusMap connects you to are located on the [Australian Government: Geoscience Australia website](http://services.ga.gov.au/). Some of the same data is available for download through [their catalogue](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/).

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I downloaded the shp from the catalogue and it worked that way.